# Invoke-Expression doesn't work witha CertificateThumbprint argument

Tags: powershell

I want to remotely make WinRM listen to the HTTPS port using PowerShell.

If I activate the "HTTPS mode" manually, my remote command works well using this function

```
function Execute-Remote {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(mandatory=$true)][String]$command
    )

    Process {
        $finalCommand = "start cmd.exe '/C " + $command + "'"
        Invoke-Expression -Command $finalCommand
        return $finalCommand
    }
}

#Works
Execute-Remote "WinRM delete winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS"
#Command sent : start cmd.exe '/C WinRM delete winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS'
```

But, as soon as I add the certificate thumbprint, it doesn't work anymore

```
#Doesn't work
Execute-Remote 'winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS @{CertificateThumbprint="example"}'
#Command sent start cmd.exe '/C winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS @{CertificateThumbprint="example"}
```

I guess that it is the argument that doesn't pass.

I tried using variables and casts. The command that I try to execute remotely is exactly the same as the one I use to activate HTTPS manually but it does nothing.

What do I miss?

Comment: Please elaborate "doesn't work" - do you receive an error? What happens? (FWIW the thumbprint in your example is not valid, but I guess you just put nonsense data there)

Comment: I get nothing, no error message, but the "HTTPS mode" is not activated. Yeap I have put nonsense in this example.

Comment: `Execute-Remote` is not a standard PowerShell cmdlet. Where does this come from, and what is it supposed to do?

Comment: Oh my... It's better with function definition, you're right

Comment: The problem arises b/c `Invoke-Expression` (which [should be avoided anyway](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)) interprets the `@{...}` as a PowerShell hashtable, which `cmd` can't process. Try `& cmd /c $command`.